# Blender 4.1 USD export not applying modifiers

Tags: modifiers, export

Very pumped about the USD armature and shape key export features added in 4.1. But when I tried it out just now, many of my modifiers are not being applied on export like they used to. So far I've noticed simple deform and subdivision modifiers that aren't exporting. Is there a trick to this now? I've looked all around for a checkbox or something like there is with .glb exports, but I've got nothing. I won't be able to use this feature for my animations in this state.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got to digging around in the more detailed release notes (check the link below). Turns out this is not a bug. It was a known consequence of the changes. Too bad it came with some major compromises. I'm going to have to gum up my files with an un-subdivided version for animation, and a subdivided version for export. Hope they figure out how to solve this soon.

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/c6d61e8586